# importing CSV into mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, csv

I have inserting my csv file into MYSQL.Sometimes it does but there are some special characters in the database like 0, 'Ã8.I'm using zend framework.

```
public function indexAction() {
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $path = 'c:/RAA/test.csv';
    $row = 1;
    $result = array();
    if (($handle = fopen("c:/RAA/test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            $row++;
            for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
                $result = array(
                    'id' => $data[$i],
                    'name' => $data[$i],
                    'description' => $data[$i]
                );
            }
            $db->insert('test', $result);
        }
    }
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check your default charset !
Force it in the `application.ini` like this :

```
resources.db.params.charset = utf8
```

Replace `utf8` (if needed) by the charset you are using !

Comment: Thanks for the sudden reply.IS my code correct??

Comment: Still am getting application error

Comment: Don't see an obvious problem ... so i think yes. You really have to check the charset of : your code file, your db table and ths connection between your code and the table (doing this by my solution ;))

Comment: Give me the print stack error

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using MySQL's built-in `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement to import that CSV file into database. Depending on how many rows you've to import, that will greatly improve the import time, since it's a simple query vs. a bunch of queries over database server. Take a look at [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) documentation for more information, there you'll find examples on how you can apply that in your code.

Comment: Thank you for that.How to find the charset which I'm using